# Preprocessing with g++ and specs-file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c-preprocessor, newlib

The question refers to arm-none-eabi-g++ 6.2 and linking against newlib-nano.

When I preprocess a **C-source** with `-specs=nano.specs`, the file `newlib.h` from the directory `newlib-nano` is included:

```
echo '#include <string.h>' |\
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6_2-2016q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -specs=nano.specs -x c -E - |\
grep '^# 1 .*newlib\.h'
```

outputs `# 1 "/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6_2-2016q4/arm-none-eabi/include/newlib-nano/newlib.h" 1 3 4` (as expected). This is because the file `nano.specs` contains (among others) the lines

```
%rename cpp     nano_cpp
 
*cpp:
-isystem =/include/newlib-nano %(nano_cpp)
```

But if I feed a **C++-source** through the same compiler

```
echo '#include <string.h>' |\
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6_2-2016q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -specs=nano.specs -x c++ -E - |\
grep '^# 1 .*newlib\.h'
```

the output reads `# 1 "/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6_2-2016q4/arm-none-eabi/include/newlib.h" 1 3`.

In other words: The specs-file is ignored.

I am aware that I should include `<cstring>` instead of `<string.h>` in C++ sources and that GNU g++ is commonly invoked by `…/arm-none-eabi-c++` instead of `…/arm-none-eabi-gcc -x c++` but I did that to carve out the *small* difference. And: this does not change the matter.

**Question**: What do I have to add to the specs-file to let C++-files include `newlib-nano/newlib.h`?

Answer (score 1):

It had been a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1661882). It has been fixed. It will be in the “6-2017-q1-update”.